# Visual Studio Server Explorer Error: Login failed for user DOMAIN\USERNAME

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, authentication, dns

After creating a database file in Visual studios server explorer earlier this month my domain name of my computer was chaned (lets say previously is was OLDDOMAIN and now it is NEWDOMAIN) After my domain name had changed i am now unable to access any of my database files. I am also unable to create any new database files from Visual studios server explorer.

The error message i am getting is:

```
Login failed for user: 'NEWDOMAIN\GLEN'
```

How can i access my old database files (.mdf) or create a new one from within the visual studios server explorer?

N.B. My Authentication is set to Windows only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to Log in as a system administrator into the database server and give your new user the correct access you require. If you don't have a local user or an SA type account; you might need to log in as your old domain user to give your new domain user that permission.

If you don't have that permission; create  new database server on your machine and attach the database files; (take a backup of the originals) you should then be able to access your content again.

Comment: Ok so my database and files are not on a server they are on my local machine. I do not have a SA account as it is usuing Windows Authentication. How can i log in as my old domain user? If i cant how would i create a new database server on my machine? and attache the database files?

Comment: Assuming you are running sql express; copy the ldf / mdf files to somewhere safe just in case. Uninstall it via the control panel. Download and reinstall the correct express version or reinstall from your visual studio disk. Copy the files to the data / log paths you choose during setup and attach them using sp_attach_db (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259611(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: You could also try and log in with your old credentials with the network cable unplugged; windows sometimes caches credentials - will depend how they migrated your machine to the new domain

Comment: I am not running any version of SQL Server as stated in my origional post i created/tring to connect to the tatabase through server explorer in visual studio 2010. I tried logging in with my old credentials and this did not work.

Comment: Sorry; your post is tagged sql-server so I assumed that you were working with sql

Comment: Well it is an SQL-Server Database but im not using SSMS to connect to it.

Comment: You are going to have to go with the uninstall / reinstall and attach your database files route. I know MS don't recommend it but it is oftentimes useful in the real world to have a sql logon you can use when domains are acting up / changing etc.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and re-installing with no luck getting the same error message.

Comment: When you reinstalled SQL Server what user did you tell it to run as? Did you follow my advise and setup a sql user or is it all integrated authentication

Comment: Like i said previously i am not using SQL Server i am using Visual studio and this is what i re-installed. And i still have no access to the database and i am still unable to create a new database.